# Securing a connection checking SSL Certificate?

Tags: java, android, security, ssl

I'm doing an internships.
Here they give me a code of an Android application that have been revisione by an agency for the code security and told me to change some points present in a document.
Now they fear for the information leakage because the application doesn't check for the SSL certificates when connecting to the bank server, risking a "Man In The Middle" attack.

Is there any class that i can use to check expirency date of the cert. or if it is trusted?

An example of a http connection in the app:

```
           trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new CustomSSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            HttpParams bhttpparams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(bhttpparams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(bhttpparams, "utf-8");
            bhttpparams.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(bhttpparams, 20000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(bhttpparams, 200000);
            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));
            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(bhttpparams, registry);
            client = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, bhttpparams);
            client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, -1), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("", ""));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(urlws);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"), 8);
```

Comment: Android SSL stack is secure by default. Just throw away any custom SSL stuff and use the defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

The vulnerability is here. Remove it.

But I would question both the competence and the sanity of anyone who gave this task to an uninformed intern without a proper briefing, and you can tell them I said so. I would also be asking some severe questions about how this line of code ever got there in the first peace, and about the inadequacy of the testing that allowed it to remain.

Comment: by removing that automatically it will check if the cert is expired and if is signed by one of the Certification Authority, check if the domain name of server is the same in the cert and check if the CA that signed the cert is trusted?

Comment: What if i put this: sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

Comment: @Marvin Yes yes yes and yes. All but the final trusted-signer check happen anyway. Can't answer your second question but you should be able to do that yourself from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, and i think i'll have to change that `trustStore.load(null, null); ` too